# ElasticSearch.net/NEST SniffingConnectionPool switches to port 9200 when using custom port behind proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

When using the SniffingConnectionPool it seems that Elasticsearch.net switches to port 9200 after the initial http.settings request?

I'm setting up the ConnectionPool with an IEnumerable as follows:

`var nodes = cfg.Nodes.Select(x => x.Uri);
var pool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodes);`

The uris passed uses port 92. When debugging the requests, I can see that the first request is correctly made and we get 200 OK. However, the following HEAD request uses port 9200?

11  200 HTTP    X.X:X.X:92  /_nodes/http,settings?flat_settings&timeout=500ms   5 121       application/json; charset=UTF-8

12  502 HTTP    X.X.X.X:9200    /   512 no-cache, must-revalidate   text/html; charset=UTF-8

Do I miss something? Worth to notice is that our cluster is reversed proxied by Nginx, and uses 9200/9300 to communicate internally.

Edit: The http property of http.settings looks like the following:

```
"http" : {
        "bound_address" : [
          "[::]:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address" : "X.X.X.X:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      }
```

Maybe the SniffingConnectionPool parses that content and starts using 9200?

Comment: Can you show the response of the first call, `X.X:X.X:92 /_nodes/http,settings?flat_settings&timeout=500ms `?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. I guess that the http property of the nodes is of interest.

Comment: Thanks. The client uses the `publish_address`es returned to seed the client with nodes in the cluster. Since you're proxying through nginx, I think `SingleNodeConnectionPool` is probably more suitable here

Comment: I'm currently using the StaticConnectionPool, which seems to be working fine. The SniffingConnectionPool worked with elastic 1.x and a older version of elasticsearch.net. Would it be possible to change the http port in the config of elasticsearch(to the nginx port) as node communication is on 9300?

Comment: That _should_ work too